# server resources in live video broadcast

Tags: memory, video, streaming, resources

how much ram do i need to run a server with red5 and broadcast live video

I am starting a project that will include live video broadcasts from all over the world and it is expected to have at least 1000 users viewing those videos in real time.

After looking around a bit i have decided to use RED5 to handle all the video streaming/recording, based on the fact that it is free and open source, but i am still open to other options (that don't include buying a FMS license).

now i need to know how many resources will red5 be demanding to the server if lots of users start accessing the site and watching the videos that maybe 50 different people are broadcasting.

i was thinking on renting a VPS with 512 MB of ram and 800 GB of bandwidth,

```
will that be enough?

will i need to get something with more resources?, maybe a dedicated server?
```

or maybe the best thing for me to do is rent some hosting that offers video streaming services of some kind?

Thanks, Fortes

Answer (score 1):

512Mb of RAM for 1000 users streaming video? No chance. We use FMS at our office with 4gb, and less than half the capacity of your projection and it runs out of memory sometimes.

I know you said that you're using RED5 rather than FMS but the memory utilistation will still be immense. Especially if you start streaming HD.

You might want to look into a professional streaming company. I can't think of their name off the top of my head but we used to deal with one who had Points of Presence all over the world and would automatically sync your data to all their POPs so that your worldwide users could just connect to their local source. It wasn't cheap, but neither is a dedicated server, which is what you will ultimately be requiring.

Still, try it with a VPS. Maybe start a 2gb of ram and see how it goes. If you need more in the future, then try to design your solution so you can migrate it to another provider if need be.